# Why is it impossible to gather parent.window.location from iframe when different sites are involved on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cross-domain

Let's suppose that I am developing a website which will be used as a widget inside `iframe`s of the users. Let's suppose that I intend to analyze things done by users on my little widget and I want to have some aggregated data by hosts (for instance, how many users visited from website1 and how many users visited from website2).

To achieve this, I would prefer to be able to read `parent.window.location`. Unfortunately, I am not able to do so because of Chrome's restrictions. Currently, to resolve the issue, I need to do some unintuitive hacks, involving `postMessage` inside the `iframe` to ask the `parent` to send its host and to receive a response from the parent to be able to do these analizations. However, this is obviously much inferior to my intention, because:

- the outer page will need to execute the `script`s specified which makes the usage of the `iframe` more complicated and confusing
- nobody forces the outer page to execute the `script`s designed for it and there is absolutely no technical guarantee that the received data will be accurate

As a result, I wonder why `parent.window.location` is unreachable in chrome from the page inside the `iframe`?

Comment: But why can't we use the contents of parent.window.location in a readonly manner?

Comment: Basically, if we could realize what the possible harm of knowing that information is, then we could answer the question. The thing is that either browser(s) have a very good reason to do so which I am unaware of, or there is no reason whatsoever, hence my question :)

Comment: The parent window could contain secret information in its location's query string.

Comment: @idbehold, I would be perfectly fine if I could reach only the parent window's window.location.host and protocol, just the information. If I could reach it like this: parent.window.host, then it would be perfectly suitable.